# Copying only shapefiles which have specific field attribute in another folder using ArcPy?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, copy

I have 100 shapefiles that all have 2 fields in common called `Type2017` and `Type2018`. The whole of the fields have only one number (1 or 2 or 3). fo example, Type2017  = 1 or Type2018 = 2

[image]

I would like to copy those shapefiles which one of these fields have been filled with number 1.

Usually I use this code for copying shapefiles to another folder:

```
NewFolder = WORK_DIRECTORY + r'/01_SHP'
copyFeatureClass = os.path.join(NewFolder, os.path.basename(Shapefile))
arcpy.CopyFeatures_management(Shapefile, CopyFeatureClass)
```

But I don’t know how to input the field value that I want .

Comment: You would like to copy the shapefiles where either the Type2017 or Type2018 field is completely populated with 1 or has at least one record populated with 1?

Comment: Only copying the shapefile in different location.
Because I don’t know out of 100 shapefile which  one has fields that filed with number 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am assuming you have created the list of shapefiles. You can read the attributes with the searchcursor and copy if 1 is found (only checking the first row):

```
for shape in shapelist:
    with arcpy.da.SearchCursor(shape,["Type2017","Type2018"]) as cursor:
        for row in cursor:
            if 1 in row:
                #Add copy code here
            break
```

Answer (score -2):

```
arcpy.env.workspace = r'PATH_TO_FOLDER'

list_fc = arcpy.ListFeatureClasses()
out_path =r'OUTPATH'
for fc in list_fc:
    arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(fc, "temp_fc")
    arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("temp_fc", "NEW_SELECTION", 'Type2017 = 1 OR Type2018 = 1')
    Num = str(arcpy.GetCount_management("temp_fc")) 
    if Num != "0":
        arcpy.CopyFeatures_management("temp_fc", out_path +"/" + fc)
    else:
         print('Deleted empty shapefiles')
```

Comment: Dear @BERA, fixed my mistake. It was working, when there was no selection empty shps were returned. Now it checks for that and only when selection occurs shapes are created.